# Highlight UITextView text

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have a UITextView in which I would like to add a background to the text (hightlight it).
I want everything but new lines to be highlighted. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `NSAttributedString` or `UITextView` `selectedRange`, depending on what you really want?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure I need the backgroundColor of the NSAttributedString but I'm not sure on how to parse and find lines that are just empty new lines and not apply the backgroundColor on them.

Comment: With `NSAttributedString`, I'm not sure if empty lines would have the background. Did you checked beforehand?

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately adds the background to newlines too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate (`enumerate(_:in:option:)`) on the `NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor` to find change only when it has a background.
Then, you can use a regex, or a while loop with `range(of:)` to find where they are, and remove the `.backgroundColor` on them:

With sample code on Playgrounds:

```
func highlights() -> UITextView {

    let tv = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
    tv.backgroundColor = .orange

    let text = "Hello world! How are you today?\nLet's start do some testing.\nAnd this is a long paragraph just to see it to the end of the line."
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0),
                                                     .backgroundColor: UIColor.systemPink]

    let first = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    let second = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\n", options: []) else { return tv }
    second.enumerateAttribute(.backgroundColor, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: second.length), options: []) { attribute, range, stop in
        guard attribute as? UIColor != nil else { return }
        guard let subrange = Range(range, in: second.string) else { return }
        let substring = String(second.string[subrange])
        let ranges = regex.matches(in: substring, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: substring.utf16.count))
        ranges.forEach {
            second.removeAttribute(.backgroundColor, range: $0.range)
        }
    }
    let total = NSMutableAttributedString()
    total.append(first)
    total.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\nNormal Text, nothing to see here\n"))
    total.append(second)
    total.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\nNormal Text, nothing to see here\n"))
    tv.attributedText = total
    return tv
}
let tv = highlights()
```

[image]

Side note:
I didn't handle the case if you have in the string `"\n   \n"`, that might need some changes in the regex pattern.
After a quick test, then `NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\n(\\s+\n)*", options: [])` might do the trick.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! :)